# Metadata API: readMetadata

Tags: soap-api, metadata-api

I read metadata from use [`readMetadata`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_readMetadata.htm) via SOAP API

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header
        xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <SessionHeader>
            <sessionId>XYZ</sessionId>
        </SessionHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body
        xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <readMetadata>
            <type>Profile</type>
            <fullNames>Admin</fullNames>
        </readMetadata>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I got is a full details of the `Profile`.
Is there any ways if I just want only `applicationVisibilities` field ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's only available in the file-based API.

Comment: @sfdcfox, you refer to [`retrieve `](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_retrieve.htm) ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The readMetadata request is going to return the full profile object, you would need to parse out the applicationVisibilities elements explicitly in whatever code is handling the SOAP response.